# AWS amplify authentication, enable only sign in - not sign up

Tags: authentication, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

From all the great tutorials I looked for of how to add an auth module for a react app in amplify. The only type of module I see is a complete feature of sign in + sign up.

What I'm trying to achieve is:

1. Set up a custom Cognito user pool and add users to the pool manually.
2. Add custom sign-in/login UI + code to a react amplify app.
3. Disable anyone but me to add new users to the Cognito user pool manually.

The website I'm working on is an internal website and I don't want anyone to be able to sign up via AppSync or the react client.

Please help :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This won't be very difficult - you simply *don't* implement the front-end functionality to add a new user. Then, in your Cognito user pool config, there is an option **`User sign ups allowed?`** which you would set to `Only administrators can create users`.

Edit: Also, consider using [the hosted UI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-integration.html), it may save you some front-end work.